# Advantage of Spring boot Actuator running on different port

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In **Spring Boot**, it is possible to have different ports for the server and management:

```
server.port=80
management.server.port=8081
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of running Actuator (management) on different port to the server?

Answer (score 2):

Probably others but how we used it is to limit access to the actuator. i.e. we expose `server.port` to the web but require VPN for access to the actuator.

Answer (score 1):

When going reactive with Spring WebFlux underneath, the main difference is that Spring Runs another Netty server when server.port and management.server.port are different. In server logs it looks like below:

```
...
o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8080
o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path ''
o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8085
...
```

Another Netty instance ends with another EventLoopGroup for Actuator's requests. Another EventLoopGroup means completely independent thread pool and event queue for processing these requests. The main advantage is responsive /actuator/health endpoint in case of full event queue of primary EventLoopGroup.

Comment: could this actually be a problem? since only health of 8085 is being monitored?

Comment: @hamid Health does not monitor port but state of the application. State of the application is independent of the port you access it by. The only problem I can imagine is when health on port 8085 responds 'ok' and another (webapp) port is inaccessible, possibly by misconfiguration issue.

Comment: but there will be two imbedded web containers that run on 2 different ports, just pointing out that the _main_ web container is not being monitored